# How to set custom userAgent in service worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have some server side code which depends upon userAgent. the code was working fine because we were setting up custom user agent on client side. but after enabling PWA on our site i am not getting my custom userAgent.
I just want to know, how to set custom userAgent in service worker?

Comment: Did you manage to keep appended string in User agent with service workers? I am struggling with similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should help:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", event => {
   // inject custom UA string
   event.request.headers.append('User-Agent', 'MyAwesomePWA/1.0.0');
   event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
}
```

Links:

- [Fetch in service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Custom_responses_to_requests)
- [Headers in fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/headers)
- [User agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent)

Comment: Thanks Man, I will try given solution and let you know after it.

Comment: Hey Man, Thanks for solution, I tried it and got that we can't mutate headers in fetch event inside service worker, Thanks.

Comment: Well, in that case, try creating a new request